# How to get data from Database with a range?

Tags: python, django, database

So i want to make a range from a specific date to current date.

I make like this:

```
    context_data['newNotifications'] = Notification.objects.filter(
    emailStudent=request.user).filter(time=request.user.viewedNotifications).count()
```

But i want all records within the `time` values in range from `request.user.viewedNotifications` to current time.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with *to current date and hour*?

Comment: can you furthermore share your models?

Comment: viewedNotifications = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.today())

Comment: Soo curent date and hour means the current date and time 2021-05-02 22:08:53.074874+03:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the [`range` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range)?

Basically you could do:

```py
import datetime
# ...

context_data['newNotifications'] = Notification.objects.filter(
    emailStudent=request.user).filter(
        time__range=(
            request.user.viewedNotifications,
            datetime.datetime.now()
        )
    ).count()
```

So your `.filter()` argument would be `time__range=(start_date,end_date)` where `start_date` comes from your request and `end_date` is `datetime.datetime.now()`.

Comment: i tried this, but i get this error: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: What's the value of `request.user.viewedNotifications`? Is it a `datetime.datetime` object? Or is it a string?

Comment: <class 'datetime.datetime'>

Comment: What happens if you remove the `emailStudent=request.user` filter? `Notification.objects.filter(time__range=(start_time, end_time)).count()`

Comment: Ohh, sorry. Now i see 'time__range', the __range its a function / attribut :)). Thanks for all :)

Comment: glad it worked, I was beginning to doubt myself 

Comment: yep. thanks. I can't give you +1, because i don't have reputation (min 15)

Comment: I think you should be able to mark the answer as correct though, which will give you some points too.